# contact 7 plugin stops some pages from working properly

Tags: plugins, css, javascript

I started to use contact 7 plugin and I'm having a slider and some effects on other images when i activate the plugin they stop working this is the web page

```
http://www.digitalways.com.sa/
```

I don't understand what it do! if it stops the javascript or css files but I searched in the files if it has the same names and stopping them from working but it have different names

i tried to add this code to function.php so i could add jQuery by the right way but it gave me server error

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
function my_init() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.3.2'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
 }
  add_action('init', 'my_init');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution i just added all scripts together

Answer (score 0):

It's not the Plugin that is at fault, but the Theme.

The Theme enqueues a custom version of jQuery, which you should **never ever** do. Also when the jQuery plugin is initialized, you need to use noConflict wrappers like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

I assume that Contact Form 7 uses jQuery as well, but since the Theme does it wrong, this causes a conflict.

Comment: Fränk thanks for reply but what do you mean by custom version is there a way to add jquery without adding the version can you please explain more

Comment: jQuery is shipped with WordPress Core. If you want to use jQuery in your Theme, all you need to do is to add wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); in your functions.php. Please keep in mind that all scripts in a Theme need to be correctly enqueued via a custom function in functions.php: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: thanks Fränk but i want to ask one more question when i add the code to function.php should i add something else in the header part to use this function

Comment: There is no additional code in header.php needed. Your header.php file should only contain HTML in most cases. The way it works with WordPress is that you write your own PHP functions in the Theme's functions.php file, and you hook this function to an action. WordPress will then take care of putting the code in the correct place (i.e. enqueuing Javascript in the head of the HTML document).

Comment: i tried some codesand they gave me server error thats why i was adding it to the header i cant find the correct way

Comment: Adding it to the header is what causes the problem in the first place. If you get a "server error", then it might be time to level up your PHP skills. This tutorial should teach your the correct way: http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 0):

ok i added this code to function.php it didn't give me " server error " but i think there still something missing because jquery still not working

```
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpcandy_load_javascript_files' );
 wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/jquery-1.8.2.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.8.2', true );

wp_register_script( 'jquery-defaultvalue.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/jquery-defaultvalue.js', array('jquery-defaultvalue.js'), '1.0', true );

wp_register_script( 'tytabs.jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/javascript/tytabs.jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-defaultvalue.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'tytabs.jquery' );

if ( is_front_page() ) {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-defaultvalue.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'tytabs.jquery' );

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function my_theme_prefix_load_javascript() {

    wp_register_script( 'jquery-defaultvalue.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/jquery-defaultvalue.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_register_script( 'tytabs.jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/javascript/tytabs.jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-defaultvalue.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tytabs.jquery' )

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_prefix_load_javascript' );
```

Comment: there is something wrpng in that code when i add it to function.php it gives me an error

Comment: Could you post the error message that is displayed?

Comment: it is the braces before the add action '{'and i also tried to ignore the error and run the code but it not working

Comment: hi frank thanks for all your support i really appreciated that i think may be the problem because of the coflict of some script in header and footer like this one <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tabsholder").tytabs({
       tabinit:"1",
       fadespeed:"fast"
       });
 $("#tabsholder2").tytabs({
       prefixtabs:"tabz",
       prefixcontent:"contentz",
       classcontent:"tabscontent",
       tabinit:"3",
       catchget:"tab1",
       fadespeed:"normal"
       });
});
-->
</script>

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: no i tried to remove the script but still not working